# Incident report

Tags: professionalism

Is it improper/bad practice to write incident reports in a form format. If so, is there any reason as to why employers hand out incident report forms rather than getting employees to write "proper" incident reports?

Comment: What's the difference between an incident report form and a "proper" incident report? Do they both capture vital information reliably?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Tell me what happened..."

"Well Bobby Sue was dancing on the table top, because he's a giant man baby, and Billy Joe was humping the stuffed camel in the corner. Brandy got that camel while she was in Japan. I don't really know why she got the camel but it was right after she broke up with Billy Joe. And between Sally Jesse, Jamie Joe and Stu there were doing some weird version of the macarena. And then a customer drove through the shop window and Suzanne spat her drink out all over Stan's nice suit. It was a really nice suit he got it at..."

There's a lot of information in that pseudo report above. And to the person saying it, it all seems important. But the reality is the person asking the question was probably hoping for less information about the stuffed camel and more information about the car driving through the shop window. Things like the time, who was there, was anyone injured, was anything damaged. A free form report leaves a lot of room for the imagination, if that's the word. They leave room for the question answerer to decide what is and is not important. They leave room for 'colourful' commentary. If a company is hiring a lawyer to evaluate an incident, a common response, then there may be things that come up during these colorful reports that people don't really want investigated. Drama or vendettas may come up. And, perhaps most commonly, a lot of kruft is introduced to your data, a lot of *stuff* that isn't really useful or important.

The long and short of it is that forms allow for consistency in reporting and ease of consumption. If an incident cannot be captured by a form it may be valuable to attach an additional written comment on the issue but, for the most part, issues can be broken down into a general 'who, what, where and when' at least for the first pass.

Comment: Nice writing - I love the part about the stuffed camel :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the form you originally linked (a bit wary about clicking an internet link to a word doc!), but I'd say in my opinion that the main reason to use a form is that the employer needs to capture certain bits of information in case of an incident, so easiest way of ensuring this is to give you a form with defined questions.  A free form write up risks missing things that might be needed.